# Sharing notification mails from Dropbox

Tags: email, dropbox

Quick question.

Right now, when I send a bunch of people a link that I'm sharing from Dropbox, I don't get any "talkback" email confirming that the link was sent, and none of the people I'm sending it to can see who else I'm sending it to.

This is intended to be secure just to those people, and work isn't willing to spring for a team Dropbox account yet.

Is there a way I can get a mail receipt, and all the recipients can see each others' names on the email, just from within Dropbox?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but that feature is not used by DropBox or any other cloud storage I know of (box.com for example). They probably will add something like that soon after the security breach that both DropBox and box had a couple of days ago, but at this moment you only get notifications via email when someone shares something with you.

I think DropBox Business allows you to select what users can share links to a file, but it doesn't send email confirmation to the sender of the link.

The best you can do is send the receiver a heads up before you send the link, ask them to let you know right after they downloaded the file, and then disable the link.

Though any link you sent prior to May 5th has been disabled already by DropBox after the breach, but you should disable the links a couple of hours after sending it.

Comment: Google Drive did it, which is why I was asking this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up just sending a notification message to myself and forwarding that message on to everyone else. Takes care of the receipts/recipient visibility issues fine, but it still feels a bit clunky.

If anybody knows a better way, I'm leaving this question open.